# Laravel route prefix not redirecting properly

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes, laravel-routing

What's wrong with this code?

```
Auth::routes();
Route::get('/',function (){
    return redirect('admin');
});
Route::get('login', ['as' => '/', 'uses' =>'Web\AuthController@showLoginPage']);
Route::get('register', ['as' => '/', 'uses'=>'Web\AuthController@showLoginPage']);
Route::prefix('admin')->group(function (){
    Route::get('/','Web\AuthController@showLoginPage');
});
```

When I try to hit http://localhost/restaurant/ it redirects me to http://localhost/restaurant/admin which is fine but the problem is on this admin URL which says:

> Not Found The requested URL /restaurant/admin was not found on this
>   server.

Comment: What Laravel version you are using? I don't see you register `restaurant` routes here. Can you share us the code where you register `restaurant` routes?

Comment: Use This



Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function () {
    Route::get('/','Web\AuthController@showLoginPage');
})



Hope it's work.

Comment: @krisanalfa I am using laravel 5.5

Comment: @jitendrakumar Its still not working

Comment: I'm sure you're installing Laravel in a subfolder, in this case, it's `restaurant`. Am I right?

Comment: can you please show output of `php artisan route:list`

Comment: seems like routing is overlapping

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure all these things are fine on your end-

1. Rewrite module should be enabled for .htaccess
2. Proper permissions on the folders as mentioned in the Laravel documentation. (**storage and bootstrap/cache folder**)

You can activate the **rewrite** module on ubuntu like this-

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Then restart the apache-

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

If you are using windows then follow this-

1. Open the file **httpd.conf** in your apache folder. (Backup this file before making changes)
2. Find **#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so** and remove the hash "**#**".
3. Restart your apache.